# How to make Bottle return an error if a port is already being listened to?

Tags: python, bottle

I'm working based on Bottle's "Hello World" example, which can be found here:
https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html

```
from bottle import Bottle, run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

My problem is that this code can be run multiple times and then only the first instance will be the one actually doing the serving. Is it possible to make the program return an error to indicate that the port is already being listened to?

Comment: Small suggestion: `return ["Hello World!"]` instead of `return "Hello World!"`

Comment: @ron.rothman - I just copied the example. Why is returning a table better here?

Comment: https://github.com/PerimeterX/perimeterx-python-wsgi/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty check to see if a port is open before running your bottle application could be useful.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8000))
s.close()
```

Code above will try to bind to socket 8000 on localhost and will fail if the socket is already in use returning a `48` error `Address already in use`. If it succeeds then it'll close (unbind) port 8000.

Comment: It's a simple solution, but I went with this one. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pick a free port first:

```
s.bind("127.0.0.1", 0)
free_port = sock.getsockname()[1]
s.close()
```

This is prone to a race condition, but it's less likely to hit it than if you bind to 8000 first and then close.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the error:

```
try:
    run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)

except Exception as exc:
    print 'run exited: {}'.format(exc)
```

Running this when the port is already bound yields

```
> python test.py
Bottle v0.12.8 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

run exited: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

---

Though I admit it isn't clear to me why you want to print the error yourself when the stack trace you're already getting basically does the same thing.  In any case, the above should work.  Hope that helps!

Comment: That's the problem - there is no error if you run multiple instances. At least I am not getting one. :)